# jQuery add class to random div after random delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class "flip" to a random "child" div, after a random time period between 0.5 and 5 seconds. The class should then be removed three seconds later.

The divs are laid out as:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
    <div class="child"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
    <div class="child"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
    <div class="child"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
    <div class="child"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
    <div class="child"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

and the jquery that I have so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $children = $(".child");
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var $d = $children.not(".flip");
        $d.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $d.length)).addClass('flip');
        if ($d.length == 1) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, Math.floor((Math.random() * 4500) + 500));
});
```

Not too sure how to remove the class again after 3 seconds tho?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setTimeout` at the end of your function in the interval:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $children = $(".child");
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var $d = $children.not(".flip");
        var $el = $d.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $d.length));
        $el.addClass('flip');
        setTimeout(fucntion() { $el.removeClass('flip'); }, 3000 );
        if ($d.length == 1) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, Math.floor((Math.random() * 4500) + 500));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From you code since you want to add the class only once, along with a timeout timer, you will have to use another extra class as well

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $children = $(".child");
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var $d = $children.not(".done");
        var $el = $d.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $d.length)).addClass('flip done');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $el.removeClass('flip');
        }, 3000)
        if ($d.length == 1) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, Math.floor((Math.random() * 4500) + 500));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2tnzceds/)

---

Another option is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $todo = $(".child");
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var $el = $todo.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $todo.length)).addClass('flip');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $el.removeClass('flip');
        }, 3000)
        if ($todo.length == 1) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        $todo =$todo.not($el);
    }, Math.floor((Math.random() * 4500) + 500));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2tnzceds/2/)